# 18.04 Boot freezes at "Started Hold until boot process finishes up" boot reboot, FYI I'm not using ubuntu as dual

Tags: boot

I tried to install some updates and after that when I rebooted the laptop it runs some commands and at last shows "Started hold until boot process finishes up. " Ctrl+alt+f2 opens command line but there is no display whatsoever. I tried recovery mode and deleting some files but that is of no use as I already had enough memory. Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: While booting to grub may not be issue, this will show configuration and we can see if something looks wrong. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair From recovery mode have you tried fsck (must be read only) and separately enabling network & run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` ?

Comment: I installed lightdm and now display is showing but after login it does not display any icon or anything, just a wallpaper and logs out soon after the log in, and it continues no matter how many times I login

Answer (score -1):

From a shell via recovery mode, try this:

```
stat /
```

If the owner and group of / are anything other than root.root, then run:

```
echo "chown root.root / && sync && shutdown -r now" | sudo sh
```